# How to convert table columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with userids and IP addresses in them. The table is called `whoread`.

I need to convert the userids to usernames. The table `user` has userids, and usernames in them for the conversion.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply apply `JOIN` to get the username from another table....

```
SELECT b.usernames ,a.ipaddress
FROM whoread a JOIN user b 
ON a.userid= b.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a query like this :

```
 SELECT username FROM user WHERE userid = *idyou'relookingfor*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT b.username 
FROM whoread a, user b 
WHERE a.user_id=b.user_id;
```

Comment: Oh, how I hate this style of joining.